# (C++ inheritance) storing objects with common parent in stl container

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I am storing an objects with common parent in stl container (actually stack), but calling a virtual function on object inside of it results in calling an implementation in this common parent. See demo code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class Z
{
        public:
                virtual void echo()
                {
                        cout << "this is Z\n";
                }
                int x;
};

class A: public Z
{
        public:
                virtual void echo()
                {
                        cout << "this is A\n";
                }
};

int main()
{
        A a;
        a.x = 0;
        Z z;
        z.x = 100;
        stack<Z> st;

        st.push(a);
        st.top().echo(); // prints "This is Z"
        cout << "x = " << st.top().x << endl; // prints 0

        st.push(z);
        st.top().echo();  // prints "This is Z"
        cout << "x = " << st.top().x << endl; // prints 100

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::stack<Z*>` to avoid slicing. (or `std::stack<std::unique_ptr<Z>>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, containers of objects and polymorphism don't mix : You are **slicing** your objects of type `A` into objects of type `Z` when you push them in the container (because the container is really expecting and storing objects of `sizeof(Z)`)

Use `std::stack<Z*>`, or `std::stack<std::unique_ptr<Z>>` to manipulate pointers to your base class.

---

See also : [What is the slicing problem in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You have [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing):

You should use `std::stack<Z*>` or `std::stack<std::unique_ptr<Z>>`.

Answer (score 2):

What you observe is *slicing*. Your stack stores `Z` objects, so even if you construct an `A` object, it will not be stored in the stack - an `Z` object will be constructed from `A` and stored.

You cannot store in container by value if you want polymorphism. Use `stack<unique_ptr<Z>>`.